# apns-python-wrapper device token issues

Tags: iphone, python, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

To use the module apns-python-wrapper here: http://code.google.com/p/apns-python-wrapper/ you need to convert your iPhone's APNS device token, however, I'm not sure how to convert it.

Here is the fresh new token returned from the device: 8fa9c60685c158a3cf6f9c5de164b3817e68a075fcfdafcd982aa4b3d2ca99c7

And this is what it needs to look like:
Qun\xaa\xd4R\x11zu\x07\x04\x9dG\xe6\x96j&\x95Y\x9d\x91~\xcc`z\n\x88O\xc0\x9c\xf6\xca

Note that is not a direct conversion. Any idea on how to convert the first token to the second in Python?

Comment: I presume the second value is the binary form of the token you need to send to APNS.  Are you sure it is?  But binascii.a2b_hex('8fa9c60685c158a3cf6f9c5de164b3817e68a075fcfdafcd982aa4b3d2ca99c7') != 'Qun\xaa\xd4R\x11zu\x07\x04\x9dG\xe6\x96j&\x95Y\x9d\x91~\xcc`z\n\x88O\xc0\x9c\xf6\xca' Why?  Is the device doing some encoding of the device token before it sends it?  If so, you need to know what, and may need a key.  Is it deliberately intended to not be a direct conversion, or are you inferring because you can't convert it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the tokenHex(yourDeviceToken) method instead of token(yourDeviceToken) and it should work fine. I had the same problem and when I changed the method, it did the conversion inside this method.